# How to split a string in sql server using stored procedure and insert the data to table

Tags: sql, database

```
<pre>update d 
  set d.Price = null 
from dbo.SalDocumentDetail d 
left join dbo.StkWarehouse w on w.WarehouseID = d.WarehouseID 
where DocumentID=" + 1 + " 
and DocumentTypeID=" + 2 + " 
and FiscalYear= " + 2016 + " 
and isnull(isPrescription,0) <>1 
and w.POSType is null 
and ProductName BETWEEN ''C' 'AND' 'M''
and Country LIKE ''%land%'''</pre>
```

**Actually this string is only a sample one my original string is very large . i am not getting a point that if i break this string than how many variables i have to make to capture the data also after splitting the string i want that to be inserted into data table containing columns as  Felid and Value?**

```
I want my result like :
<pre>
Felid                         Value
 DocumentID=                    1 
 DocumentTypeID=                2 
 FiscalYear=                   2016 
 isnull(isPrescription,0) <>=     1 
 w.POSType is=                 null 
 ProductName=                   C
 ProductName=                   M 
 Country=                       land 
</pre>
```

Comment: help me please I want the Query

Comment: khalid your question is unclear. where is the string, what is the schema for dbo.SalDocumentDetail and dbo.StkWarehouse what is the desired result.  Are you wanting columns as rows?

Comment: I want function split after Where like my result i want two columns Felid  and Value     This i want split after (where DocumentID=" + 1 + " 
and DocumentTypeID=" + 2 + " 
and FiscalYear= " + 2016 + " 
and isnull(isPrescription,0) <>1 
and w.POSType is null 
and ProductName BETWEEN ''C' 'AND' 'M''
and Country LIKE ''%land%''')

Comment: khalid try taking a look at your question simply restating your question in the same manner is not going to make me understand.  Plenty of people have looked at it and thought about it and presumably not understood what you want otherwise you would see more action and help.  So you need to help us understand better by providing more detail in your question by editing and letting us know schema and search/where string.

Comment: I post Answer Look the function I think you will understand me

Comment: so you want to take this as entire string 'Felid                         Value
 DocumentID=                    1 
 DocumentTypeID=                2 
 FiscalYear=                   2016 
 isnull(isPrescription,0) <>=     1 
 w.POSType is=                 null 
 ProductName=                   C
 ProductName=                   M 
 Country=                       land ' and split it up to a table of Filed & Value

Comment: Yes I want that Please 
I tried to solve it but I don't Find any solution

Comment: another question are really just trying to use the string to filter in a where condition like the first code in your question? If so it won't do you that much good to split the string to rows.  You would be better off splitting them to columns or simply searching the string in the where statement it self.

Comment: yes I want split after where condition if find any 'and,or,like,is,between ' split it like my result 
example:
  columns :   Felid                           columns :  Value
  Rows     :   DocumentID=               Rows:   1

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>I Use this function but this function split 'and' not split like what i want in my result i want split 'and,or,like,is,between ' if function find any this split it to two columns (Felid and Value)</pre>

<pre>ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
(@List NVARCHAR(MAX),@Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255))
RETURNS @Items TABLE(Felid NVARCHAR(Max),Valu nvarchar(MAx))
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @ll INT=LEN(@List)+1,@ld INT=LEN(@Delimiter); 
WITH a AS
(SELECT     
[end]=COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,1),0),@ll),                      
[VlaueFelid]=SUBSTRING(@List,(select
CHARINDEX('where',@List)+5),COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('=',  @List,0),0),@ll) ) ,
[Value]=SUBSTRING(@List,(select CHARINDEX('="',@List)+2),(select CHARINDEX('and',@List))-(select C`enter code here`HARINDEX('="',@List)+3))              
UNION ALL
SELECT 
[end]=COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,[end]+@ld), 0),@ll),                    
[VlaueFelid]=SUBSTRING(@List,[end]+@ld,   COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('=',@List, [end]+@ld),0),@ll)-[end]-@ld),
[Value]=SUBSTRING(@List,[end]+@ld+16,  COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('=',@List,[end]+@ld),0),@ll)-[end]-@ld-5)                      
 FROM a WHERE [end]< @ll) INSERT @Items SELECT[VlaueFelid],[Value] FROM a WHERE LEN([VlaueFelid])>0 RETURN;
END</pre>
```

Comment: Yeah Khalid this had issues with your string for sure.  However, there are plenty of answers on how to split a string to rows I suggest doing a search for some and read up. here is one to get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: OK Matt Thanx for help 
but my issues multiple cass how to make function split string if found 'and,or,is,between,like' i read in many website i don't have solution